# Проверка синтаксической функции выделенных слов

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

***У дома*** стояли мальчишки. "У дома" в данном случае является обстоятельством.
 ***У дома*** есть большая веранда. (определение)

*Деревянная лестница вела **на чердак**.* "На чердак" — обстоятельство.
*Лестница **на чердак** вся прогнила*. (определение)

*Звёзды на тёмном небе **словно блёстки**.* "Словно блёстки" — определение.
*Звёзды на тёмном небе **словно блёстки** рассыпаны.* (обстоятельство)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. У дома есть большая веранда.

Веранда есть (у чего?) у дома. "У дома" — дополнение.

> 2. Звёзды на тёмном небе словно блёстки.

Мне кажется, здесь "словно блёстки" — сказуемое.

> [1.7. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/706-17_tire_mezhdu_podlezhaschim_i_skazuemym.html) не ставится, если при сказуемом есть сравнительный союз (как, будто, словно, точно, вроде как, всё равно что, что и др.) (Звёзды будто алмазы; Небо точно море);:

-

> 3. Звёзды на тёмном небе, словно блёстки, рассыпаны.

По-моему, здесь "словно блёстки" — сравнительный оборот, а это значит, во-первых, что нужно выделить его запятыми, во-вторых, что это обстоятельство (в предложениях сравнительные обороты обычно являются обстоятельствами).

Comment: М_Г: _Звёзды на тёмном небе, словно блёстки, рассыпаны_. (???) Лучше, по-моему, обойтись без запятых. Ср.: _Звёзды на тёмном небе **блёстками рассыпаны**_. См. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом _как_ **не выделяется запятыми**:

1) если на первый план выступает значениие обстоятельства образа действия (обороты с _как_ можно заменить в этих случаях формой творительного падежа существительного или наречием)...

Comment: @slava1947 Сравним примеры, приведенные Розенталем. С запятой: *Под ним, как океан, синеет степь кругом (Кр.);
Как чайка, парус там белеет в высоте (Фет);* Без запятой: *Как град посыпалась картечь (Л.) — ср.: градом посыпалась; 
Как демон коварна и зла (Л.) — ср.: демонически коварна;* Я думаю, у нас на первый план выступает сравнение, а обстоятельство образа действия. (См. два первых примера)   Поэтому я поставил запятую.

Comment: @slava1947 Заменить формой творительного падежа можно и в тех примерах, где запятая стоит (Как чайка, парус там белеет в высоте -> летает чайкой), но этот формальный признак не всегда работает.

Answer (score 0):

> > **У дома** есть большая веранда. "У дома" - определение.

То есть "Веранда есть (какая?) - у дома"?! Думаю, нет. Думаю, дополнение.